# jenkins/hudson running on glassfish stops without exception overnight

Tags: jenkins, glassfish, hudson

I ran hudson/jenkins on glassfish. After I start up the domain, everything seem to be working fine. However, after I left it running overnight, I cannot access the hudson/jenkins webpage. The server is stopped for some reason.

Here is last few lines in the log I grabbed from glassfish.

```
[#|2013-05-23T15:25:34.076-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Loading plugin email-ext|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:34.076-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginManager|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading plugin - git|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:34.108-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=105;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context ''|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.028-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Loading plugin git|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.029-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginManager|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading plugin - htmlpublisher|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.131-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Loading plugin htmlpublisher|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.131-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginManager|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading plugin - jfreechart-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.169-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Loading plugin jfreechart-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.169-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginManager|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading plugin - jna-native-support-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.362-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Loading plugin jna-native-support-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.363-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginManager|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading plugin - xpath-provider|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.418-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Prepared all plugins|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.418-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=85;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Loading plugin xpath-provider|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.420-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=85;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin analysis-core|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.420-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=87;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained null|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.421-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=85;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin birt-charts|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.422-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin checkstyle|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.424-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Checking cyclic dependencies|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.423-1000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Failed Initializing plugin email-ext
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$2.run(PluginManager.java:315)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at hudson.model.Hudson$4.runTask(Hudson.java:667)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:35.424-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin email-ext|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:36.405-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version|_ThreadID=105;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.623-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin git|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.625-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin htmlpublisher|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.626-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin jfreechart-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.627-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin jna-native-support-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.628-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Initializing plugin xpath-provider|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.654-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Discovering plugin initialization tasks|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.654-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Started all plugins|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.656-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=93;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Augmented all extensions|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.656-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained null|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.658-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained null|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.660-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=89;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loaded all jobs|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.660-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Loading global config|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.663-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained null|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:37.756-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=85;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Attained Finalizing set up|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:38.034-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.Hudson|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Completed initialization|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:38.038-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener|_ThreadID=70;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 51560|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:38.577-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=105;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0671: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:38.579-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=105;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|CORE10010: Loading application __admingui done in 7,354 ms|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:38.580-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=105;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The Admin Console application is loaded.|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:25:46.675-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.hudsonci.events.ready.ReadyDetector|_ThreadID=136;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Hudson is ready.|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:31:33.290-1000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=148;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:31:33.324-1000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=149;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:31:34.001-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=75;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Redirecting to /common/index.jsf|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:31:34.421-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=149;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.458-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping javadoc|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.459-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping maven-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.463-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping ant|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.464-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping subversion|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.465-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping cvs|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.465-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping jfreechart-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.466-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping analysis-core|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.466-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping birt-charts|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.467-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping checkstyle|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.468-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping email-ext|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.468-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping git|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.469-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping htmlpublisher|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.469-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping jna-native-support-plugin|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.470-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping ssh-slaves|#]

[#|2013-05-23T15:34:19.471-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.PluginWrapper|_ThreadID=159;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopping translation|#]

[#|2013-05-24T00:49:15.556-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.FingerprintCleanupThread|_ThreadID=340;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Started Fingerprint cleanup|#]

[#|2013-05-24T00:49:15.563-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.FingerprintCleanupThread|_ThreadID=340;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Cleaned up 0 records|#]

[#|2013-05-24T00:49:15.564-1000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.FingerprintCleanupThread|_ThreadID=340;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Finished Fingerprint cleanup. 7 ms|#]
```

I don't see the exception that will cause it to stop. I started the domain from command line. When I ran "java -jar jenkins.war" in the windows command line, samething happened. It worked fine at the beginning, but it stopped overnight. Anybody out there is able to run jenkins on the command line overnight (over two days)?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Jenkins started to shut-down at '2013-05-23T15:34:19.458' - should check what happened around that time.

Comment: I am using Java 1.7u7. How do I get more log information out of Jenkins? I looked everywhere - -